Was there some significance for mentioning of Jesus' age in Lk 2:42?
We read in Lk 2:41-42 ( NIV):

Every year Jesus’ parents went to Jerusalem for the Festival of the Passover.  When he was twelve years old, they went up to the festival, according to the custom.

We see the mention of twelve years of age also in Mk 5:42 and in 2 Kings 21:1. In the first case, Jesus raises a twelve-year-old girl from the dead. In the second one, Manasseh becomes the 14th King of Judah, at the age of 12 years, eventually  turning out to be a disastrous  king. While the girl enters a new life at age 12, Manasseh enters spiritual death at age 12. As for Jesus, he tells  his parents at age 12 that his life is exclusively at the service (and disposal) of the Father.
My question is : Was there some significance for mentioning of Jesus' age in Lk 2:42 ?

because it was going to be His bar- mitzvah!

Because you bring up other places where 12 year olds are mentioned it sounds like you are looking for something other than what's going on in the Luke passage you mentioned. Are you looking for an answer on being 12 years old in the Bible generally or in Luke 2:42 specifically?

Thanks, Dottard. Would you please narrate bar- mitzvah for the BHE audience ? And thanks, David D. Let us first hear from Dottard.

Do you have some reason to suspect significance rather than simple coincidence?

@Dottard 12 is for girls. 13 is for boys. You should explain how at 12 years old He could be considered "of age."

The tradition of bar mitzvah was created in the Middle Ages. And the ceremony takes place at the age of 13. So, it has nothing to do with the quoted text.

The number 12 is the number of something becoming completed. In Jewish tradition, a Bar Mitzvah is held at the age of 12 symbolizing that childhood is completed, and they are now considered young adults.
In the passage, this is mentioned because Jesus realizes he is no longer a child, and, "must be about His Father's business" as an adult.
This may also speak of the biblical age of accountability.
It also makes another statement in that same passage that most people overlook. In Verse 51 it says "Then He went down with them and came to Nazareth, and was subject to them". Other versions say "and was obedient to them" showing that from this point forward, there was accountability for disobedience that a child under the age of 12 could get away with.

The biblical age of accountability is 20.

Your answer is good, but I'm going to suggest that there's no reference to an "age of accountability".   The Greek phrase,  ἦν ὑποτασσόμενος αὐτοῖς is a periphrastic construction with the present of 'to be' coupled with the imperfect passive participle of "to submit".  I think the passive participle does, in fact, convey the idea of 'accountability'.  The present tense helper verb then conveys the idea of "past tense, continuous action".  So, the sense is, "...he continued to be accountable to them."  He had been accountable all along.  Nothing had changed.

I am not coming at it from a grammatical view. You would need the original text for that. which you don't have. I am using context of passage and Jewish culture. I think it shows the possibility of Jesus possibly not being perfectly obedient before this in the time of childhood, but it doesn't say that. However, it could also be a statement that Jesus was not attached to His earthly parents the way that others were, since the text reads that Mary kept all this in her heart, realizing that this boy is not really hers. He will soon be doing the will of God, and separating himself from her.

ארקדיוס @ - at the end of 12 or the beginning of 13, aren't they same? It doesn't change the context of Jesus' coming of age and Mary realizing this and having to keep it in her heart that He does not belong to the family the way other boys are to theirs.

@ארקדיוס The practice of bar/bat-mitzah demonstrates the people understood 12 or 13 as the point at which a child was accountable for their actions. Old enough to pay the Temple tax does not preclude being accountable at an earlier age to obey the Law, for example.

@Revelation Lad Bar mitzvah is a medieval invention. It was unknown in the times of Jesus.

During the talmudic era and early medieval times, a ceremony made no sense, because a minor was permitted to participate in all religious observances as soon as he was considered mentally fit [to do so]. He was called up to an aliyah to say blessings over the Torah and was supposed to wear tefillin , or phylacteries. The minor was even encouraged to fast on Yom Kippur. Two years before he turned 13, a child fasted until noon, and a year before his majority, he fasted the whole day. …

… Gradually, during the later Middle Ages, this situation underwent a change. The religious rights that the Talmud accorded to the minor were now restricted. He was deprived of the right to be “called up” to the reading of the Torah. He was no longer permitted to wear tefillin. The attainment of majority gained new importance as an attainment of new religious rights, and the ground was prepared for a ceremony around the bar mitzvah , as a boy 13 years old was beginning to be called.
https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/history-of-bar-mitzvah/

"The modern method of celebrating becoming a bar mitzvah did not exist in the time of the Hebrew Bible, Mishnah, or Talmud. Early rabbinic sources specify 13 as the age at which a boy becomes a legal adult; however, the celebration of this occasion is not mentioned until the Middle Ages (from approximately 500 CE to 1500 CE."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_and_bat_mitzvah

@Revelation Lad & Biff The biblical age of accountability is 20.
"In this wilderness your bodies will fall—every one of you twenty years old or more who was counted in the census and who has grumbled against me. Not one of you will enter the land I swore with uplifted hand to make your home, except Caleb son of Jephunneh and Joshua son of Nun. As for your children that you said would be taken as plunder, I will bring them in to enjoy the land you have rejected." (Numbers 14:29-31)

@ the guy who writes his name in Hebrew so it is difficult to reply with his name. Num 14 does not say anything about an age of accountability. You have inferred it from the text, the way that others have about Jesus. You have made an assumption that you are using as proof as apposed to a viable option. There is a lot of info we don't know. What we do know is to not trust wiki-anything. We also don't know about pre-existing rituals before the modernized version of Bar Mitzvah. And there was a lot lost in the diaspora. Bar Mitzvah may be based on an earlier ritual that ceased around 66 - 70 AD.

@ארקדיוס You are confusing the age of accountability with those who were old enough to go in and take the land. "Take a census of all the congregation of the children of Israel, by their families, by their fathers’ houses, according to the number of names, every male individually, from twenty years old and above— all who are able to go to war in Israel. You and Aaron shall number them by their armies." (Numbers 1:2-3) Those who rebelled against God (Numbers 14) effectively refusing to go to war were those who were considered old enough to go to war (Numbers 1).

Explain how I am confusing it? I understand your point of being eligible to be a soldier at 20. That is not the question

@Biff You have got a point about wikipedia. That is why the first quote I used was from www.myjewishlearning.com. A legit source of information about Jewish life and customs. They know the history of bar mitzvah. The tradition is less than 1500 years old. It is a well documented fact.

@Revelation Lad & Biff - The Age of Legal Maturity - in Biblical Law, JOSEPH FLEISHMAN,
Bar-Ilan University
https://janes.scholasticahq.com/article/2370-the-age-of-legal-maturity-in-biblical-law/attachment/6311.pdf

@ Hebrew name - Modern Jewish sources are not honest about ancient Judaism. They are 2 different religions. Some cultural things remain only.

@ארקדיוס Majority of Biblical scholars state the age of accountability is not specified. Using events in Numbers is a reach. 1. It is not logical a person 20-years old, who is eligible to go to war, had not previously been determined to be mature enough to be accountable for their actions. 2. If those living under the Law understood the age of 20-years, the practice of bar/bat mitzvahs would not reflect 13/12 years old. 3. The census connects those who would be punished for the refusal to take the land.

After doing some research, I think I may have the answer to this question.
The text definitely does not talk about the bar mitzvah. That custom was not known in Jesus' times. As a matter of fact, it must have been introduced well after the codification of the Talmud, since bar mitzvah is not mentioned there even once.
Why does Luke tell us that the story happened when Jesus was twelve years old? Well, as many people know, Luke wrote his gospel primarily for the Greeks. It was Matthew who wrote for the Judeans, as one can guess from the number of Hebraisms and midrashic explanations. Luke must have been writing about something familiar to his audience. Something universal to the whole Hellenistic world of Jesus' days. It is probable, that the custom of the day for a boy around twelve years old would be to start learning his father's trade. Which would explain what Jesus meant answering Mary in Luke 2:49:

And He said to them, “Why [is it] that you were seeking Me? Did you
not know that it is necessary for Me to be in the things of My
Father?” (Literal Standard Version)
He said to them, "Why were you looking for me? Did you not know that I
must be doing the works of my Father?" (New Heart English Bible)
And He said to them, “Why did you seek Me? Did you not know that I
must be about My Father’s business?” (New King James Version)
And he said to them, How is it that ye sought me? knew ye not that I
must be about my Father's business? (Webster's Bible Translation)
"Why is it that you have been searching for me?" He replied; "did you
not know that it is my duty to be engaged upon my Father's business?"
(Weymouth New Testament)
And he said unto them, 'Why is it that ye were seeking me? did ye not
know that in the things of my Father it behoveth me to be?' (Young's
Literal Translation)

Luke seems to suggest that Jesus identified himself as the son of God since His early adolescence. Which did not change His relationship with Mary and Joseph. In fact, Jesus learned His adoptive father's trade also:

“Isn’t this the carpenter’s son? Isn’t his mother’s name Mary, and
aren’t his brothers James, Joseph, Simon and Judas? (Matthew 13:55)
Isn’t this the carpenter? Isn’t this Mary’s son and the brother of
James, Joseph, Judas and Simon? Aren’t his sisters here with us?” And
they took offense at him. (Mark 6:3)


Good point, ארקדיוס .But you need to support it with references from the scriptures, or at least Jewish history. Perhaps, the case of Manasseh helps. His father might have died before Manasseh turned 12, but the latter was kept waiting to become the king once he turned twelve.

Perhaps Luke was written for Levites in general and Theophilus, a retired High Priest, in particular. Thus the four Gospels have a specific point of view for the four types of people. Mark - Gentiles; Matthew - Jews; Luke - Levites; John - children of God.

@Kadalikatt Joseph Sibichan Like I said, that may be written in the context of the Hellenistic culture of the eastern Mediterranean. So it may not have any scripture to back it up. The Torah was given in the context of the middle-eastern culture of 15th century BC. The NT uses the elements of the contemporary Greco-Roman culture to convey certain spiritual things. The patron-client relationship being the most obvious.

@Revelation Lad The possibility that Theophilus was one of the priests can't be ruled out. Who knows? Luke writing for the Levites does not seem plausible thought. Why would he? He was a Greek physician. A gentile. It is more likely that the synoptics follow the pattern set by the Pilate's sign, written in Hebrew, Latin and Greek. The etymologies of the Authors' names also link with that idea. Matthew - Hebrew. Mark - Roman. Luke - Greek.


He was inspired to do so. 2. Since God divided people into these groups, God has the responsibility to provide each group with the specific information needed to believe Jesus is the Christ. 3. It is obvious Luke writes with Levites in mind. Beginning with Zechariah in the Holy Place. Continuing with John's mother being a Levite. This event which brings together priests and their presence in the Temple. 4. Some scholars think Luke was a priest.


Regardless of the question of the bar mitzvah, the reason his age is mentioned is to show that he was still technically a boy and under his parents' control. Jesus' challenged this and affirmed that he owed his first duty to his heavenly parent, not his earthly ones.

“Why were you looking for me? Did you not know that I must be in my
Father's house?” (2:49)

However, in the end, he recognized that since he was still a boy, he had to obey his earthly parents. Thus the story concludes:

51 And he went down with them and came to Nazareth and was submissive
to them.

The next time we see Jesus, he is a man and no longer under parental authority. In Luke 8, he rejects his mother's attempt to interrupt his ministry to attend her. This time she lacks the authority to move him:

19 Then his mother and his brothers came to him, but they could not
reach him because of the crowd. 20 And he was told, “Your mother and
your brothers are standing outside, desiring to see you.” 21 But he
answered them, “My mother and my brothers are those who hear the word
of God and do it.”

Conclusion: Jesus' age was probably mentioned to establish the fact that he was an adolescent, struggling to affirm his identity as a man of God while still needing to obey his parents.  One has to wonder how things might have turned out if his earthly parents had allowed him to remain in "my Father's house."
